# File path to insert image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to insert an image into my html code, and can't get the file path correct. I have my code in a folder (Countdown) on my desktop and a sub folder (Images) with my .jpg images, but when I try to view the webpage, it just shows "test image" instead of showing the actual image. Also, it doesn't center the image either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./Images/Green.jpg" alt="Test Image" border="0" align="center"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, HTML obviously isn't my forte, but doesn't that make it a relative pathway?

Comment: Based on your description, that path should work fine.

Comment: Maybe try JPG instead of jpg

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz Why?

Comment: It is very likely that OP's server is running under a Linux distribution, whose file system is usually case-sensitive.

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz The OP states that he/she is accessing files locally from the desktop. It's likely that there is no server being used here at all. And, if it was a case-sensitive issue, the entire path (file name and all) would need to be checked, not just the extension.

Comment: Why would you expect the image to be centered? You have not written any code that would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center this you need to add a div container around your image.

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="pathToImage" /></div>
```

Your path seems right. Are you sure the image is ending with *.jpg?

Can you manually try to access the image by /Images/Green.jpg?

Comment: It should be `text-align:center;`, not `align:center`.

Comment: Ok, the text-align worked (I thought that the "align="center"" in the img src code would center it), but I'm still getting the alt text instead of the image. The image is a *.jpg. I've checked and rechecked it.

Comment: You have checked the location of the file? May your browser blocks displaying the image? Can you check - via your development tools (e.g. FireBug for Firefox) - if the file is able to access? Hover over the src-attribute.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I am using internet explorer (work computer)?

Comment: Ok, it's a security setting on the work computers. So nothing wrong with the code. I appreciate the help. I'm marking this as the answer, as it showed how to center it, and was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's sub folder within code directory use.

```
<img src="Images/Green.jpg" alt="Test Image" border="0" align="center"/>
```

Comment: That code is entirely equivalent to the code in the question. Removing `./` makes no difference.

Comment: This isn't working either. I posted it exactly as you have it.

Comment: Using ./ is not the way I was taught to specify image src. been using `src="imagefolder/filename"` for years without issue.
Refer to html schools [link]http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp[link]

if you want to navigate up one directory use ../